# Given $\angle (\vec{u} , \vec{v}) = 30^\circ$, $\Vert \vec{w} \Vert = 4$ and $\vec{w}$ is $\perp$ to both find $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} \times \vec{w}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, cross-product

I am given the following problem:

> Knowing that the angle between the unit vectors $\angle (\vec{u} , \vec{v}) = 30^\circ$, $\Vert \vec{w} \Vert = 4$ and that $\vec{w}$ is orthogonal to both of them, evaluate $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} \times \vec{w}$

I am not sure where to begin this exercise. I know that

$$
\vec{u} \cdot \vec{w} = \vec{v} \cdot \vec{w} = 0
$$

but that won't take me far.

Comment: Note that the appropriate order of operations is
$$
\vec{u} \cdot (\vec{v} \times \vec{w})
$$

Comment: Ok, noted. So the dot product comes last. And the cross product produces a vector in the same plane as $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}$ correct? How would that help me?

Comment: That's right.  Not sure yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
u \cdot (v \times w) = w \cdot (u \times v)
$$
That is, we can cyclically permute the vectors in a triple scalar product.

Comment: Mmm thats interesting. Would the answer be $2\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: Oops sorry, $4 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1/2 = 2$ ?

Comment: Well, that is one of two possible answers, assuming that $u$ and $v$ are unit vectors.  The other possible answer is $-2$.

Comment: Yes I forgot to put that on the question, I'll update it. Is the following reasoning correct? 
$\vec{w} \cdot \vec{u} \times \vec{v} = \Vert \vec{w} \Vert \Vert \vec{u} \Vert \Vert \vec{v} \Vert \sin(30^\circ) = 2$

Comment: Again, you need to be careful there.  The angle between $u \times v$ and $w$ is either $0^\circ$ or $180^\circ$.  Other than that though, you're right.

Comment: Ah ok, I see that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So it is understood that you are looking for the value of $s$ in
$$ s = \vec u \cdot \left( {\vec v \times \vec w} \right)$$

First note that $s$ is a scalar, that is a real number (the volume - with sign - of the paralleliped defined by the three vectors).
Second, since ${\vec v}$ and ${\vec w}$ are orthogonal to each other, their cross product will be a vector 
orthogonal to both, whose modulus is 
$$\vec t = \vec v \times \vec w\quad  \Rightarrow \vec v \bot \vec w \Rightarrow \quad \left| {\vec t} \right| = \left| {\vec v} \right|\left| {\vec w} \right| = 4\left| {\vec v} \right|$$

Since ${\vec u}$ is also orthogonal to ${\vec w}$, then ${\vec t}$ will lay on the same plane as ${\vec u}$ and ${\vec v}$

Then since $\angle (\vec{u} , \vec{v}) = 30^\circ$, the $\angle (\vec{u} , \vec{t})$ will be either $60^\circ$ or $120^\circ$ (don't know if you indicated oriented angle or absolute).

Thus
$$ s = \vec u \cdot \left( {\vec v \times \vec w} \right) = 4\left| {\vec u} \right|\left| {\vec v} \right|\cos \left( {30^\circ \pm 90^\circ} \right)  $$